# How to perform time stretching with pitch preservation on an AudioBufferSourceNode?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am looking for a phase vocoder in javascript or some kind of pitch-shifting / time-stretching algoritm I could use with webaudio when changing the playback speed in order to prevent the pitch from changing too.

edit:
I have found https://github.com/also/soundtouch-js
However it's not ideal because it has to have acces to the complete source file; I'm developing a system with multiple tracks (each with own gain control); so ideally I would need a system that I can connect all my nodes to instead of having to merge them or make multiple soundtouch systems.

Comment: http://webaudiovocoder.appspot.com and https://github.com/cwilso/vocoder